# Write value to parallel port register

Tags: c, module, linux-kernel

I'm trying to write  to my lpt register with the function `outb(0x378,val)`;
well.. I tried to debug with the call `int ret=inb(0x378);` I always get the `ret=255` no matter what value I insert with `outb` before.

*I'm writing on the kernel mode since my program is a driver, therefore I didn't use `ioperm()` etc.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know for a fact that you have a parallel port installed at that address?

Get yourself a small low-current LED.  Stick the long end in one of pin 2 (LSB) to pin 9 (MSB) and the short end in pin 25 (ground).

Try writing various values and see if you can get the LED to change by the bit value of what you write.

This should work (unless as previously mentioned you've gotten it programmed in an input mode)  Being able to read back the port value is less certain, depending on the type of parallel port and implementation details (for example, you probably couldn't with the buffer chip that implemented it in the original PC)

Also note that most USB "printer" adapters don't give you bitwise register access.  Something hanging off of the PCI or PCMCIA, etc may also have problems with direct register access at the legacy port address.  There are nice USB parallel interface chips such as the FT245 and successors which you can use if you don't have a "true" parallel port hanging off the chipset available.

Comment: The led is an excellent idea I will get it.. 
I'm working on Linux CentOS do you know how can I discover wht is my parallel port address by checking it within the OS files..?

Comment: You could try something like dmesg | grep parport and see if that comes up with anything.  /proc/ioports might be better.  But this is more about what the kernel detects in the course of trying to load drivers for than what is necessarily there.  Perhaps where you should really look is in the bios settings?

Comment: thank you Chris your advices really helped..
I didn't have much time to progress with my module.. Hope to update you if you will be intrested.

Answer (score 2):

You have the parameters of `outb` function wrong, correct order is :

```
outb(value, port)
```

so you have to change your code to do:

```
outb(val, 0x378)
```

For more details please read [`Linux I/O Programming Howto`](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming.html) .

Comment: `please note the order of the parameters`.  No kidding.  +1.

Comment: either way it won't work..
with outb(val,0x378) I still get same result.

Comment: Parallel port is not a loopback device if you want to read what you have written you need a loopback device which will just echo what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the direction register? If it is set as input then you will read what is on the port.

Answer (score 0):

inb(0x378) is not required to return what was written; at least I've seen chips to behave so. Well, since you, at some point, have called outb, you know what's on anyway.